# How to setup HTTPS with Laravel Homestead on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, https, homestead

I'm working on a project with Laravel Homestead which needs a SSL certificate in order for me to be able to use HTTPS. All my co-workers use Mac OS, but I'm the only one which uses Ubuntu (ubuntu 18.10).

How do I setup HTTPS for Laravel Homestead on Ubuntu?

Comment: And what's your question? What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

As Homestead is just a Vagrant Virtual Machine with Nginx as default webserver you can either choose to use a [Let's Encrypt certificate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04) or a [self signed certificate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04).

I would recommend a self signed certificate out of these 2 options, because your domain probably doesn't point to your development machine and using the DNS-01 challenge is something you have to do at least every 3 months manually.

My own shorter way to create a self signed cert is:

1. create a file called **v3.ext**

   ```
   authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
   basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
   keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
   subjectAltName = @alt_names
   [alt_names]
   DNS.1 = *.example.com
   DNS.2 = *.example2.com
   ```
2. openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 2048
3. openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
4. openssl req -new -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key
5. openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 3650 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext

Comment: Hi Thomas, since Lucas is a new member i think it would be great to increment your answer with step by step.

Comment: @RenoirReis I agree, I can copy the steps from the linked tutorial of course but it's less clear

Comment: That'll be great initiative, i already had this doubt some many times. Looking forward to your edit.